# Regex expression with decimals, one letter and a question mark

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make a suvat calculator so one can input decimals, a letter (e.g., S) and a question mark if you do not have a value.

Tests that will be valid include "2.3", "S", "?" but not values like "2.5s", "??", etc (only one type, can't have decimals AND a letter in the same input box)

Is there a regex expression for this? So far I have only got the regex for the decimal number:

```
 ^[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)
```

I did also try a way simpler one but I would like a more developed expression for later on.

```
[0-9sS.?]
```

Comment: Do you want to validate these strings? Try `@"^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[A-Z?])\z"`.

Comment: By "decimals", did you mean numbers with or without fractional parts, or only those with fractional parts? Also, are lowercase letters allowed? All Unicode letters, or ASCII only?

Comment: Yeah, numbers with or without fractional parts. And yes, lowercase letters are allowed and ASCII. I should've been more explicit with what inputs I would like.

Answer (score 1):

if i got your use case right, then this might work:

```
^(\?|(\d+\.?\d+)|\S)$
```

Read it as: The word contains either one question mark,
or a numeric value with propably a dot and numbers behind that
or a single letter

You can try it our here:
https://regex101.com/r/wLGJhJ/1

Comment: Hi, this almost works, it allows one letter only, but it allows all ASCII characters? For example, I need a decimal number, or "S" only or a "?" only. Is there any expression that can do this?

Comment: If I get you right you want only a single letter of the alphabet? If so you could replace \S with [A-Za-z]{1}

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
@"^(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?|[A-Za-z?])\z"
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[0-9]+` - one or more ASCII digits
  - `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - an optional occurrence of `.` and one or more ASCII digits
- `|` - or

  - `[A-Za-z?]` - an ASCII letter or `?`char
- `)` - end of the group
- `\z` - the very end of string.

See a [.NET regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%7C%5BA-Za-z%3F%5D%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=2.3%0D%0AS%0D%0As%0D%0A%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A2.5s%0D%0A%D1%84%0D%0A%D0%AF%0D%0A%3F%3F%0D%0A%E0%A7%AA%E0%A7%AA.%E0%A7%AA%E0%A7%AA&o=m).